# Using result of a query in input parameters for a common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have such a query:

```
select distinct Project_Id,keyword,SE_Id from Table1 ;
```

It returns me almost 14.000 rows.

I have another SQL-query which looks like the following:

```
with DateWithValue as (

SELECT * 
  FROM DateTable as dt LEFT JOIN Table1 as PK on dt.Date_ID=PK.Load_Date and PK.Project_Id=? and Pk.keyword=? and SE_Id=?
LEFT JOIN Table2 as pr on PK.Project_ID=pr.Project_ID
where PK.Domain is not null and 
dt.Date_ID>= (SELECT min(Load_Date) from Table1 where Project_Id=? and keyword=? and SE_Id=? ) and
dt.Date_ID<= (SELECT max(Load_Date) from Table1 where Project_Id=? and keyword=? and SE_Id=? )
--order by Date_ID
)
select * from DateTable as dt Left join DateWithValue on dt.Date_ID=DateWithValue.Date_ID 
where DateWithValue.Date_ID is not null
order by dt.Date_ID
```

In this query `?` should be replaced wthe ith result of the first query.

How can I combine these two queries? do you have any Idea for me

UPDATE: I have changed my query as following (to analyse better, I hold an example):

```
    SELECT 
    dt.Date_ID
    ,Pk.keyword
--  ,pr.Company_BK
--  ,pr.Project_URL
    ,t2.pos_position
    ,pk.Project_Id
    ,PK.SE_Id
FROM 
    DimDate as dt 
    JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id,
    Min_Load_Date =  MIN(t1.Load_Date),
    Max_Load_Date = MAX(t1.Load_Date)
FROM
    [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] t1
    where keyword='aktueller gaspreis pro kwh' and Project_Id=383601 and SE_ID=1  
GROUP BY
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id
    )
     as PK 
        ON dt.Date_ID >=  PK.Min_Load_Date
        AND dt.Date_ID <  PK.Max_Load_Date
        --AND PK.Project_Id=? 
        --AND Pk.keyword=? 
        --AND SE_Id=?
        LEFT JOIN [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] t2
          on Pk.Project_Id=t2.Project_Id and PK.keyword=t2.keyword and PK.SE_Id=t2.SE_Id and t2.Load_Date >=  dt.Date_ID and t2.Load_Date <=  dt.Date_ID
--    LEFT JOIN MDM.SearchMetrics_Project as pr 
 --       ON PK.Project_ID=pr.Project_ID
```

with this query I get such a result:

[image]

The structure is exactly what I was looking for, but the new challenge is the column `pos_positin`, which has sometimes NULL values. But it should not be like this.
This column between 20180406 and 20180412 should be 19 and between 20180413 and 20180423 be 21
How can I achieve that with this query?

UPDATE 2: I got it here is the solution:

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT 
    dt.Date_ID
    ,Pk.keyword
--  ,pr.Company_BK
--  ,pr.Project_URL
    ,t2.pos_position
    ,pk.Project_Id
    ,PK.SE_Id
FROM 
    DimDate as dt 
    JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id,
    Min_Load_Date =  MIN(t1.Load_Date),
    Max_Load_Date = MAX(t1.Load_Date)
FROM
    [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] t1
    where keyword='citire gaze' and Project_Id=1458724 and SE_ID=79
GROUP BY
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id
    )
     as PK 
        ON dt.Date_ID >=  PK.Min_Load_Date
        AND dt.Date_ID <  PK.Max_Load_Date
        --AND PK.Project_Id=? 
        --AND Pk.keyword=? 
        --AND SE_Id=?
        LEFT JOIN [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] t2
          on Pk.Project_Id=t2.Project_Id and PK.keyword=t2.keyword and PK.SE_Id=t2.SE_Id and t2.Load_Date >=  dt.Date_ID and t2.Load_Date <=  dt.Date_ID
--    LEFT JOIN MDM.SearchMetrics_Project as pr 
 --       ON PK.Project_ID=pr.Project_ID
    )
    select a.Date_ID
    ,a.keyword
    ,a.Project_Id
    ,a.SE_Id
    ,ISNULL(a.pos_position,x.pos_position) pos_position
     from cte a outer apply
(select top 1 pos_position 
    from cte b 
    where b.Date_ID<a.Date_ID and 
        b.Project_Id is not null and 
        b.pos_position is not null and 
        a.pos_position is null order by Date_ID desc)x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want and skip a ton of performance pain...

Change you're 1st query to this...

```
-- #first_query...
SELECT
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id,
    Min_Load_Date = CONVERT(DATE, MIN(t1.Load_Date)),
    Max_Load_Date = CONVERT(DATE(MAX(t1.Load_Date))
FROM
    dbo.Table1 t1
GROUP BY
    t1.Project_Id,
    t1.keyword,
    t1.SE_Id;
```

Then you're second query would just look like this...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dbo.DateTable as dt 
    JOIN #First_Query as PK 
        ON dt.Date_ID >=  PK.Min_Load_Date
        AND dt.Date_ID < DATEADD(DAY, 1, Max_Load_Date)
        --AND PK.Project_Id=? 
        --AND Pk.keyword=? 
        --AND SE_Id=?
    LEFT JOIN Table2 as pr 
        ON PK.Project_ID=pr.Project_ID;
--where 
--  PK.Domain is not null 
--  AND  dt.Date_ID>= (SELECT min(Load_Date) from Table1 where Project_Id=? and keyword=? and SE_Id=? ) 
--  AND dt.Date_ID<= (SELECT max(Load_Date) from Table1 where Project_Id=? and keyword=? and SE_Id=? )
--order by Date_ID
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, I have updated my post. Could you please take a look at this?

Comment: Thnaks I got it! I have updated my post again. Thank you for your hint

Comment: @Kaja - Great, glad to see you got it figured out. Thank you for updating to provide your final working solution.. Well done. :)