# Using result of a SQL statement as parameter for another SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have this SQL query:

```
select distinct Project_Id, keyword, SE_Id 
from [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword]
```

The result of this query should be used in the following complex query (where I put `@ProjectID`, `@Keyword` and `@SEID`):

```
with DateWithValue as 
(
    SELECT  
        dt.Date_ID,
        LEAD(Load_Date,1,0)OVER (ORDER BY Load_Date) as  Date_ID_AFTER,
        [keyword]
        ,[DWH_ServerExecutionID]
        ,[DWH_LoadTime]
        ,[Load_Date]
        ,TopKey100=
        case 
            when [Tags] like '%prio%' and [pos_position]!=''   then [pos_pos ition]
            when [Tags] like '%prio%' and [pos_position]=''   then NULL
            else NULL
         end
        ,TopKey400=
        case
           when [pos_position]='' then NULL
           else pos_position
        end
        ,[pos_position]=
        case
           when [pos_position]='' then NULL
          else  pos_position
        end
        ,[pos_traffic]=
        case
           when [pos_traffic]='' then NULL
          else [pos_traffic]
        end
        ,[tags]
        ,[trend_date]
        ,[SE_Id]
        ,[Domain]
        ,[dbo].[CleanseURL]([Pos_url]) as Pos_url
        ,pr.Company_BK
        ,pr.Project_URL
        ,PK.Project_ID
    FROM 
        DimDate AS dt 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] AS PK ON dt.Date_ID = PK.Load_Date 
                                                  AND PK.Project_Id = @ProjectID 
                                                  AND Pk.keyword = @Keyword 
                                                  AND SE_Id = @SEID
    LEFT JOIN 
        MDM.SearchMetrics_Project AS pr ON PK.Project_ID = pr.Project_ID
    WHERE
        PK.Domain IS NOT NULL
        AND dt.Date_ID >= (SELECT MIN(Load_Date) 
                           FROM [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] 
                           WHERE Project_Id = @ProjectID 
                             AND keyword = @Keyword 
                             AND SE_Id = @SEID)
        AND dt.Date_ID <= (SELECT MAX(Load_Date) 
                           FROM [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] 
                           WHERE Project_Id = @ProjectID 
                             AND keyword = @Keyword 
                             AND SE_Id = @SEID)
    --order by Date_ID
)
SELECT 
    dt.Date_ID, DateWithValue.Domain,
    DateWithValue.keyword, DateWithValue.pos_position,
    DateWithValue.Load_Date, DateWithValue.pos_traffic, 
    DateWithValue.Company_BK, DateWithValue.Pos_url,
    DateWithValue.Project_Id, DateWithValue.Project_URL,
    DateWithValue.SE_Id, DateWithValue.tags,
    DateWithValue.TopKey100, DateWithValue.TopKey400,
    DateWithValue.trend_date 
FROM
    DimDate AS dt 
LEFT JOIN
    DateWithValue ON dt.Date_ID >= DateWithValue.Date_ID 
                  AND dt.Date_ID < DateWithValue.Date_ID_AFTER
WHERE
    DateWithValue.Date_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    dt.Date_ID
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion, how can I reach this aim in an optimal way?

Comment: I don't think you need to use those variables since your first query deos not have a `WHERE` clause, what you really need is to pass a table-valued instead of those parameters and join it with `[RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword]` table.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. could you please explain a little more in detail? what should I do? and how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if the first results should be passed as a parameter since your code is not an `SP` nor a function, mybe you are looking for a CTE or even a SubQuery, Table-Valued also can be used there. Also this line is confuse me a bit `FROM DimDate as dt LEFT JOIN [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] as PK on dt.Date_ID=PK.Load_Date and PK.Project_Id=@ProjectID and Pk.keyword=@Keyword and SE_Id=@SEID` Are you looking to pass on value? or many values?

Comment: Did I not already answer this for you yesterday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using result of a query in input parameters for a common table expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338689/using-result-of-a-query-in-input-parameters-for-a-common-table-expression)

Comment: @Sami It has more than one value. More than 14000 values

Comment: @SMorYes but it is more complicated

Comment: @CaiusJardthanks but that query was simple form and from that query I lost some Information, hence I have open a new descusion

Comment: The technique is still exactly the same. Put the first query into another CTE or derived table - or dump the result into a temp table. And all those left joins are mostly unnecessary (perhaps all of them are). It is also highly suspicious that you reference DimDate twice. And while we at it, **BE CONSISTENT!** Add the appropriate alias to every column you use - not just some of them.

Comment: And it strikes me that the entire query could be much improved - but doing that requires knowledge of your schema and your goal.

Comment: @Sami Thank you for your answer. I have updated my post [Using result of a query in input parameters for a common table expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338689/using-result-of-a-query-in-input-parameters-for-a-common-table-expression) with the this idea you have mentioned. could you please take a look at that?Why my curren query is so complex, I have written there.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to any data it's impossible to verify that this suggestion is functionally equivalent to your existing query. But, it seems you want a full set of dates (from a dimension table) with metrics when the data falls between a date range per project. **Instead of attempting to do this in a row-by-row fashion** (*which is not the best way to use SQL*) join the dimension and the metrics, but do this via a "derived table" that includes the needed min/max date ranges. e.g.

```
SELECT
      dt.Date_ID
    , PK.Domain
    , PK.keyword
    , pos_position = CASE WHEN PK.pos_position = '' THEN NULL ELSE PK.pos_position END
    , PK.Load_Date
    , pos_traffic = CASE WHEN PK.pos_traffic = '' THEN NULL ELSE PK.pos_traffic END
    , pr.Company_BK
    , dbo.CleanseURL(Pos_url) AS Pos_url /* user function */
    , PK.Project_ID
    , pr.Project_URL
    , PK.SE_Id
    , PK.tags
    , TopKey100 = CASE WHEN PK.Tags LIKE '%prio%'
            AND PK.pos_position != '' THEN PK.pos_pos ition WHEN Tags LIKE '%prio%'
            AND PK.pos_position = '' THEN NULL 
           ELSE NULL END
    , TopKey400 = CASE WHEN PK.pos_position = '' THEN NULL
            ELSE PK.pos_position END
    , trend_date
FROM DimDate AS dt
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          *
        , MIN(Load_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Project_Id, keyword, SE_Id) AS max_Load_Date
        , MAX(Load_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Project_Id, keyword, SE_Id) AS min_Load_Date
    FROM RL.SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword
    ) AS PK ON dt.Date_ID = PK.Load_Date
LEFT JOIN MDM.SearchMetrics_Project AS pr ON PK.Project_ID = pr.Project_ID
WHERE PK.Domain IS NOT NULL
    AND dt.Date_ID >= pk.min_Load_Date
    AND dt.Date_ID <= pk.max_Load_Date
ORDER BY dt.Date_ID
```

Notes

1. your where clause `PK.Domain IS NOT NULL` forces each row to have a match between the tables, hence it is useless using a left join. You would need to relax this condition if you actually need the left join.
2. you really should include the relevant table alias to all column references, I have assumed this is `PK.` if it was absent.